# Does anyone have a validation schema for Visual Studio 2010 for XHTML+RDFa?

Tags: facebook, validation, html, xhtml

Visual Studio validates XHTML 1.0 Transitional by default. There are custom solutions for validating HTML5. But if you are writing a site that uses any part of the Facebook API or the meta property tags then your HTML is probably invalid. Most people don't know to change their DOCTYPE to this:

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">

What I'd like to know is, does anyone have a way to get Visual Studio 2010 to recognize RDFa like someone hacked it for HTML5?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opengraph validation for HTML5](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6501189/opengraph-validation-for-html5)

Comment: That Opengraph question provides a workaround but is not a real answer...

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this contains what you need but you could give it a spin...

There is an update/addon for html5 webstandards

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a15c3ce9-f58f-42b7-8668-53f6cdc2cd83
http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2011/06/announcing-html5-css3-support-for.html

Comment: HTML5 is NOT equal to XHTML+RDFa so that doesn't help with this specific question.